# Venues not updating on trending list in foursquare api (Json)

Tags: json, foursquare

I am using the Foursquare api to get the json file of trending venues with checkins. I was getting results back from the JSON file earlier today, but now its returning a json file but with no venues in them. Can someone please help me figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that there are no venues trending near the location you are searching. Make sure you specify an ll parameter that is near real venues, where people would be checked in. You can visit [this page](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/trending?ll=40.7,-74) for an example query.